# Positive and negative skewed distributions

Tags: statistics, means

I have seen the following statements in several places:

1. In a normal distribution, mode=mean=median.
2. In a negative/left-skewed distribution, mode > median > mean.
3. In a positive/right-skewed distribution, mean > median > mode.

A) I am not clear on why the mode is necessarily affected by skewness. Why is this the case, is this universally true for any unimodal distribution, and/or can you point me to a proof of this?

B) I can sort of see why mean should be pulled in the direction of the skew, but is this universally true for any unimodal distribution and/or is there a proof of this?

Thanks

Comment: 2 and 3 are not always true, but they are usually true for most of the distributions you will come across, especially for continuous distributions (rather than samples from them, which have issues with the mode).  In fact the mean, median and mode can be in any relative order  - I did a note on some investigations over 20 years ago at http://www.se16.info/hgb/median.htm though this goes back much earlier to Karl Pearson and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean is generally more sensitive to extreme data or outliers than the mode or median, but the relationships you mention in your points 2 and 3 are not universally true.

However, it is also important to be clear about your definition of skewness.  To summarize some essential points from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Relationship_of_mean_and_median):

-Let $\mu,m,\sigma$ represent the mean, median, and standard deviation respectively for random variable $X$

-There are [many measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Other_measures_of_skewness) of skewness; for instance, an old notion of "nonparametric" skewness is defined as
$${\mu-m \over \sigma}$$

but the typical modern definition is the third standardized moment:

$$E\left[\left({X-\mu \over \sigma}\right)^3\right]$$

-Under this modern definition:

1. If the distribution is symmetric, $\mu=m$ and skewness is zero. If the distribution is both symmetric and unimodal, the mode also coincides with $\mu,m$.
2. For general distributions, there are many examples that break the rules of thumb you mention, as seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220181456/http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n2/vonhippel.html)